# How to count the total parameter that being sent from a method to another method

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
       for (int i = 0; i < mainArrayList.size(); i++) {

            ArrayList<String> row = mainArrayList.get(i);

            for (int t = 0; t < row.size(); t++) {
              if(condition){
                 //statement
              continue;
             else{
                 int roww = i;
                 int cell = t;
                 editFile(roww, cell);
                System.out.println("no of row:" + roww + " no of 
                     cell " + cell);
                System.out.println("FALSE");
                continue;  
               }
       } 
   }
```

I have if-else statement like above code. all the arraylist data is from the excel file that has been imported and store it inside arraylist. So basically every each of the data will be go through the condition. if the condition result is false, it will call the editFile method(code below) to edit the original file to edit the specific row and cell which the value of variable roww and cell11 that being sent. I have test it if the only 1 result is false, it can edit just fine at that specific column and row, but when I have more that one false result, it only goes to the last value that being sent.

```
public static void editFile(int roww, int cell) {
    try {

        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("xxx"));

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        for (int ff = 0; ff < roww + 1; ff++) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(roww);
            row.createCell(cell).setCellValue("FALSE");
        }
        file.close();

        FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(
                new File("xxx2"));
        workbook.write(outFile);
        outFile.close();

        System.out.printf("DONE UPDATE");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

for example i have value

```
roww = 12, cell = 10
```

and `roww = 18, cell = 20`

the editFile method will only edit the `roww = 18, cell = 20`

can someone help me? thank you in advance

Comment: I assume that the filename `"xxx"` for file input and output is the same in reality, right? How often does `"DONE UPDATE"` appear?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I separate the both file. when the new file is created, it will be a separated file. the original file still be the same. when I run the program, if  I have 2 false result, my console will output 2 times "DONE UPDATE" based on the row and cell that is false.

Comment: You take an input file, modify data for `roww = 12, cell = 10` and write it to an output file. Then you take the **unmodified** input file again, modify data for `roww = 18, cell = 20` and overwrite **the same** output file with the new modifications for `roww = 18, cell = 20` **only** while previous modifications are gone.

Comment: @MichaelButscher oh my god, now I understand. thank you Sir for helping me. I should have used the same file right? problem solved ! thank you Sir, have a nice day !

Comment: Either use the same file or load the workbook at the very beginning and then go to your loop of edits which should then update the workbook in memory instead of file(s) and after that finally save the workbook to the new file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to Michael Butscher for helping me. It is very simple mistake. I should have used the same file. I should use the same excel file for input and the same excel file for outfile.

```
public static void editFile(int roww, int cell) {
try {

    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("samefile"));

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);


        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(roww);
        row.createCell(cell).setCellValue("FALSE");

    file.close();

    FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(
            new File("samefile"));
    workbook.write(outFile);
    outFile.close();

    System.out.printf("DONE UPDATE");

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: You really should **not** using this `editFile` method for each single cell value you needs changing. For each single cell value it opens the file, creates the whole workbook, gets the sheet and the row, creates the cell, changes the value and then it writes the whole workbook to the file. You might see how less performant that is. Instead let the workbook being a class member which is created **once** at the beginning and only written **once** when ready.

Comment: @AxelRichter you mean I create a new class, and then just call that class instead of make it as a method ? this way the performance is much better?

Comment: No, that's not what I have said. I have said `XSSFWorkbook workbook` should be a class member and only created once at the beginning and only written once when all data was put in. Or for static method it could be a parameter `public static void editFile(XSSFWorkbook workbook, int roww, int cell)...` for example. In all cases you should **not** new creating and resaving the workbook from the file every single time you needs putting data in one of the cells of one of the sheets of it.